# Changing the body of mail sent to new user registration

Tags: plugins, customization, custom-field, email-verification

I am practically new in this community / forum, I hope to be as clear as possible about this question.

I would like to change the body of the email sent to new users registered on my site, since only admins can register new users, we need to change specifically the link where the user can log in, since that link will only be for admins of the site, we have an entirely different login for the users withe subscriber status which is accessed via the front end of our site, and we need that link to be replaced with the front end login URL. For the rest of the body it can pretty much stay as the default, specially the change password URL.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm betting you'll find some good info in the Codex about this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification

Comment: Please look to the right under "RELATED". This is a fairly common question here. There are many, many answers already.